# Defining Custom Error Document In htaccess file of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to define my custom error document in the htaccess file of wordpress installation. For that i have modified the htaccess file.

MY htacces file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /mysite/script.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But when i try to load a page that does not exists it goes to wordpress default error page.

What i want is that script.php file should be called when a page is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From the Codex:** *The default WordPress theme has a 404.php file, but not all Themes have their own custom 404 error template file. If they do, it will be named 404.php. WordPress will automatically use that page if a Page Not Found error occurs.*

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page

Now the Wordpress way to handle this would be:

1. Copy/rename your script.php to 404.php and put it in your theme folder
2. `ErrorDocument 404 /mysite/script.php` should read `ErrorDocument 404 /mysite/index.php?404`